# Android Kotlin: Trying to retrieve the context in a fragment results in type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am writing a piece of code that sets the options within a Spinner. Below is my code conected to the fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.alarmeventtest.R

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
class PlaceholderFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var pageViewModel: PageViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel::class.java).apply {
            setIndex(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) ?: 1)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

        // UI initialization: Set options of the drop-down menu
        // Set the contents of the drop-down menu (Spinner)
        val spinnerArray =
            arrayOf("All Events", "Your Alarms", "Non-Alarm Events")
        val alarmOptions = root.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.alarm_viewing_options)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            spinnerArray
        )
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        alarmOptions.adapter = adapter

        return root
    }
}
```

At this piece of code:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
    context,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    spinnerArray
)
```

In the function:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View?
```

I get the following error:

> Type Mismatch: Required: Context Found: Context?

**How do I convert context to a non-nullable data type**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead use `requireContext()` if you are certain the fragment is associated with a `Context` (e.g. a valid host `Activity`), like so:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
    requireContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    spinnerArray
)
```

If the fragment isn't associated with a `Context`, it will result in an `IllegalArgumentException` being thrown.

Comment: Note that `requireContext()` will never throw an exception in `onCreateView()` - your fragment is **always** attached to a context by the time that lifecycle method runs, making this the safe and correct choice for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use requireContext() instead of context. requireContext() returns a nonnull Context, or throws an exception when one isn't available instead of context.